# How to write non-english string in file in objective c

Tags: macos

I have a problem with writing file with non-english string in objective c.

Please help me .

Comment: I think it would be helpful to specify the problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to:

1- open notepad (or text edit)
2- write your text in the language you prefer
3- copy & paste it in xcode (if you use it as NSString put it inside @"" as usual)

happy coding!